# how do I create readable C++/CX document from XML generated by Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, documentation

My project is written in C++/CX on VS2015 and I am seeking a way to generate API documentation.

After googling and stackoverflow, I have tried doxygen, VSDocman,NDoc, Atomineer Pro Documentation and SandCastle, I found these tools do not support C++/CX syntax, therefore, they cannot generate correct document.

I also tried to generate XML file which VS supports. But it's hard to read XML file.

How do I generate API documentation from C++/CX? Thanks for any suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a *lot* of misconceptions about the C++/CX language extension.  You tried too many products that have no hope of getting you anywhere.  First and foremost is that it is a native C++ extension and does not generate a .NET compatible assembly.  So knock out any that try to use Reflection to parse metadata.  Out goes NDoc, VSDocman, Sandcastle.  Atomineer is out, it is just an editor add-in.

So all you got left is doxygen.

Sure, it doesn't know about C++/CX out of the box.  The FAQ points out that in order to make it compatible with a language, you need to modify [src/scanner.l](https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/blob/master/src/scanner.l)

Having a look at it, I see it already supports the C++/CLI extension.  That's another C++ language extension that supports generating MSIL.  C++/CX syntax is *very* close to C++/CLI.  Just some minor differences, like the `gcnew` keyword is too misleading and replaced by `ref new`.  But that's not the kind of syntax that doxygen cares about, it just wants to know about declarations.  Those keywords are the same.

So the only obstacle I can guess at is that you just forgot to tell it about the language.  It can't guess at it correctly from just the filename extension, .cpp and .h will get it to parse plain C++.  Modify or add this line in the config file:

```
   CPP_CLI_SUPPORT        = YES
```

And tweak scanner.l if necessary.

Comment: thanks a lot.  However,  I still don't understand why Visual Studio provides XML doc generation? it looks like redundant if cannot be used.

Comment: It was meant to generate IntelliSense info, the kind that pops up when you're editing source code.  It was never intended to produce documentation.  That it *could* be useful for doc generation is secondary, having to parse C++ is the obstacle here.